# Why does the 2nd condition in this recursive function occur twice

Tags: python, recursion

Trying to use recursion for a maze problem and made a conditional test case.
Can someone explain to me why the 2nd condition adds 20 bs instead of 10?

```
def recur_test(count, list1, status):
    if count == 10 and status == 1:
        return (count, list1)
    if count == 10 and status == 0:
        count = 0
        status = 1
        recur_test(count, list1, status)

    if count < 10 and status == 0:
        count += 1
        list1.append("a")
        print("A thread", count)
        recur_test(count, list1, status)

    if count < 10 and status == 1:
        count += 1
        list1.append('b')
        print("B Thread", count)
        recur_test(count, list1, status)

print(recur_test(0, [], 0))
```

Comment: What is a 'bs'?

Comment: b is a string that appends to the list1; i was using it to just track what is happening

Comment: Did you try to trace through it yourself? For example, by checking what the values of the parameters are at the beginning of each call? What were you *expecting* to happen, and *why*?

Comment: yeah I put a print statement at the start of the function print('start',count, list1, status); it adds 10 'a' and then count==10 is satisfied but for some reasons instead of adding 10 'b' it adds 20 of them and the 'count" value resets to 0 again even though no condition is met to reset it

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Isn't that the definition of a debugging question, though? If the OP knew why the code was breaking, they presumably wouldn't need to post a question here at all.

Comment: This functions only purpose is for me to better understand recursion; I was going to implement recursion for a maze problem but wanted to see if I added conditions it wouldn't over run so built this test function to play with it; The object of the test function is to recursively add 10 'a' and then when the condition is met it will at 10 'b's until that 2nd condition is satisfied; the result should be a list with 10 as followed with 10 bs

Comment: @ISE8 When you extend each ``print`` to also include the ``status``, does it make sense to you then?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I get """start 10 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'] 1""" and in this case i would imagine the next recursion would meet the count ==10 and status 1 and stop but it keeps going until """start 10 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'] 1""" for some reason the count resets even though no condition was met to reset the count

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I'm asking because being the author of the code implies they have a rough idea of how it is supposed work, which is not correct. The difference being whether one needs to correct an existing assumption, or build one from the ground up.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote something that was the right general idea, but doesn't actually capture the problem. I'm going to have to do actual testing. :/

Comment: Okay, I fixed it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You're conflating the OP understanding how it's *supposed* to work vs. the OP understanding how it *actually does* work. If they don't understand what needs to be achieved in the first place, they probably need to do more research before posting here. The latter type of question is perfectly reasonable, though; by definition, if you post any debugging question here at all, you don't know something about how it actually does work; if you knew that, you presumably wouldn't need to post here in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a simpler example:

```
def recur_test(value):
    if value:
        print("in first condition")
        recur_test(False)

    if not value:
        print("in second condition")

recur_test(True)
```

The way to understand this most easily is to substitute in another function that does the same thing, and call that instead of making the recursive call:

```
def recur_test_2(value):
    if value:
        print("in first condition")
        value = False
        recur_test_2(value)

    if not value:
        print("in second condition")

def recur_test_1(value):
    if value:
        print("in first condition")
        value = False
        recur_test_2(value)

    if not value:
        print("in second condition")

recur_test_1(True)
```

Now there should be no confusion: when the call to `recur_test_2` returns, `recur_test_1` keeps going, and prints the `in second condition` message a second time - since `value` has been changed.

The same fundamental thing happens with recursion - each call to the function is "separate", it just happens that the function has the same *name* each time.

Your own code has the same issue - on the call where `count == 10 and status == 0`, the one where you flip `status` to `1`, on the way "in" this switches from appending `a`s to appending `b`s, but on the way "out" those calls continue - and since `count` was reset to 0 *in that call*, it is now `0` again, and `status` is similarly `1`, so the `b`-appending branch is entered again.

There is a further complication, though: in your code, the reassignments to `count` and `status` in further-on recursive calls don't matter to the current call, but the `.append` to `list1` *does* - because it is the *same list object*, being modified in-place.

Comment: Very clearly explained! Thank you for all your help!!!

Comment: Especially when trying to make recursion work properly, it is better to think of functions as *doing some calculation and determining a result*, rather than as performing an action.

Comment: its still somewhat curious to me that if list1 is made a string I can easily see the branching as it seems to make two instances of the list1 string var; but if it is a list1 is defined as a list references to it call the same object; any reason in particular that it creates 2 instances of the list1 var as a string but references the same list1 var if its a list?

Comment: Because the way that you build the string doesn't involve modifying a string in-place (that isn't *possible* in native Python), but the way your code builds a list (there are other ways) does. Please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html .

Comment: Thanks again! you're the best =)

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement unexpectedly falls through to each of the others even when it is true. When the second condition `if count == 10 and status == 0:` is true, you set count = 0 and status = 1, then make the recursive call. The recursive call goes all the way through the "B Thread" and returns control to where you made the recursive call in that second if body. So now count and status are 0 and 1 respectively. This makes the last condition `if count < 10 and status == 1:` true, so it continues to go all the way through the "B Thread" again.

I would suggest changing the if statements to if else.

Comment: I see! on the run where count=10 and status=1; I recursively call a thread to add the 10 bs but since i have an if statement on the bottom it already has a thread to add 10 bs so therefore 20 bs are added!!! I get it now. Thanks for all the help everyone!